# Play Audio HTML5 function only work with Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, audio

Sound doesn't work with Firefox or Opera, only Chrome. I wonder if it's a compatibility issue between the sound format, but this problem **only happens when I have this files mounted on the server**. There a pattern for this? Do I need to add some like Onload event? Anyway, here is the code:

`function PlayAudio(path){

    var myAudio = new Audio(path);

    myAudio.play();

    return myAudio;

}`

And i call this function from another javascript file (in the same folder) like this:

`var background_audio = PlayAudio('../sound/back_sound.ogg')`

Any suggestion or test is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the mimetype your server is delivering the ogg-file with. It has to be `audio/ogg`.

Comment: I have loaded the file and use **Tools > Page Info** to see the full headers and content sent from a web server, the are few images that i'm using but nothing about the ogg sound file. What can i do?

Comment: if your file is accessible in the web, use www.web-sniffer.net and put in your ogg file to see the content-type. if it's local, use a http inspector like fiddler or wireshark

Comment: but it´s working ok with Opera and Chrome... does this not matter?

Comment: it does, Chrome is more forgiving than the others and may play the file in spite of a wrong mime type.. I suppose it is a mime type issue especially because you said it works local, but not on your server.